# Getting rid of the empty space after the legend property

Tags: html, css, legend-properties

I am having some issues with an extra line of space right after the legend property as seen in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G72tT/1/). Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Also, there seems to be a tab sized space between the legend (ie. Color) and the labels (ie. Red), why is this the case...?

Here is the relevant HTML markup for my problem

```
<form action="http://www.learningwebdesign.com/contest.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Color:</legend>
  <fieldset id="colors">
    <ul>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="color" value="Red">Red</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="color" value="Blue">Blue</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="color" value="Black">Black</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="color" value="Silver">Silver</label></li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>     
  <fieldset id="features">
  <legend>Features:</legend>
    <ul>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="features[]" value="Sparkley laces">Sparkley laces</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="features[]" value="Metallic logo">Metallic logo</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="features[]" value="Light-up heels">Light-up heels</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="features[]" value="MP3-enabled">MP3-enabled</label></li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the relevant CSS markup for my problem

```
     ul { 
       list-style-type: none;
     }
     ul li {
       clear:both;
     }
     form {
       width: 40em;
       border: 1px solid #666;
       border-radius: 10px;
       box-shadow: .2em .2em .5em #999;
       background-color: #d0e9f6;
       padding: 1em;
       overflow: hidden;
     }
     label {
       display: block;
       float: left;
       width: 10em;
       text-align: right;
       margin-right: .5em;
       color: #04699d;
     }

     fieldset {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       border: none;
     }
     legend {
       display: block;
       float: left;
       width: 10em;
       text-align: right;
       margin-right: .5em;
       color: #04699d;
       outline: black dotted thin;
     }
     #features label, #colors label {
       color: #000;
       display: inline;
       float: none;
       text-align: inherit;
       width: auto;
       font-weight: normal;
       background-color: inherit;
       outline: black dotted thin;     
     }
     #colors ul li {
       display: inline;
       margin-bottom: 0;
     }
     #features ul{
       margin-left: 11em;
     }
     #features ul li{
       margin-bottom: 0;
       clear: none;
     }
```

Comment: Watch for correct and consistent `HTML`. The Color is `legend + fieldset > ul`, while the Features is `fieldset > legend + ul`

Comment: [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index)

Comment: Can be fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/G72tT/4/ *But yes the HTML is incorrect*. You shouldn't wrap `input`s in `label`s, apart from consistency that @HerrSerker mentioned.

Comment: @abhitalks Of course, it can be fix, but JustinLiang has to choose one

Comment: @abhitalks Why do you mean, that you shouldn't wrap `<input>`s in `<labels>`s? I think it's totally ok.

Comment: @HerrSerker: Yes. That's perfectly valid. Confirmed with the specs. I stand corrected.

Comment: @HerrSerker, I fixed the inconsistency with my HTML for the Color and Features fieldsets but I did not notice any change in the appearance of the final output of this code. So I am wondering, how can such inconsistencies negatively affect a part of a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser default css of the `<ul>` has `margin` and `padding` of non zero values. Set these to `0`.

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

<strike>Use a normalize.css like here on[github/nomalize](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/). This will do the above and some other stuff, which makes the different browser default css more consistent between the different browsers.</strike>
Maybe think of not using `<ul><li>` for checkboxes and radio buttons. These are not "real lists" and are semantically overkill from my point of view. But this depends on your personal thinking about that.

Use the browser inspectors to see the actual used css values [See a screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGdnl.jpg).

The right jsfiddle with normalize.css included can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G72tT/5/)

Comment: Thanks for such an informative post, I had no clue you could do this on the browser, it's so useful!

Answer (score 2):

There is a margin in your ul element. Try

```
ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

also I move the `clear:both` piece of code before everything else you define for `ul` and `li`.

Comment: What about the tab sized margin on the right of Color and Features? I specified a right margin of only 0.5em but the space is much larger than this. Do you know why?